# Hyperlinks working while viewing page from web browser on PC but not on Mobile (Android)

Tags: android, html, mobile, hyperlink, tabular

To begin, my web programming knowledge is very dated. I learned some html/java back in high school about 15 years ago and for fun have decided to put it to use and help a friend make an offline web based html database for a collection of his data that up until now he's kept in nothing but word and excel docs. So there is nothing fancy here. I'm mainly just formatting and linking pages. And make a ton of use out of tables. Lame, I know.

Anyway, here's the issue I've run into...

I'm pretty much done. I've just been going and fixing mistakes here and there. Grunt work. Every so often I've tried to display it on my Samsung Galaxy Note 2 and been rather pleased with the results. I'm not using any program that alters the display for mobile or anything. Just straight html/java with a bit of css I've started to learn while taking on this project. So sometimes I have to pinch to zoom and make the page fit on my mobile device, but I'm not too worried about it.

The problem I've come across is that a series of the pages with tables on them don't appear to work correctly. Each table has links to anchor points further down the same page. On PC, these links function properly. But for some reason on my phone when I tap on those links they don't respond at all. Not every page with tables has this issue I should note, only a small cluster.

All I'm using for code is an 'a href' tag in the table leading to an 'a name' anchor further down the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be great if you can share your code and what you have tried so far with us, so it'll be a lot easier for us to help you with your problem.

Comment: That sounds like it should work. It would be helpful if you post the code that is causing the problem, so we can see if there are any errors in it. Additionally, it may behoove you to read this quick tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've got nearly 20k lines of code on this one page. What exactly do you want me to post? Well correction, 20k lines...not all of which are code.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using HTML5, `a` tags don't have a name attribute.

try using:

```
id="titleofyourchoice"
```

instead of:

```
name="titleofyourchoice"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
edit: Issue mysteriously fixed itself. I tried your id tag and it worked. Then I went back and changed it back to a name tag....still works. I'm baffled but I'll take it.